# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 1:

Tags: pandas, utf-8

[image]

The following code gives me a

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:\\Users\\vlac284\\Desktop\\Lighting\\sample_Myer\\sample_2.xlsx
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Similar postings did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an Excel format file (.xlsx) and you are trying to read it as csv (read_csv).  They are 2 different formats... that will not work.

Either save your Excel file as .csv or use a library / method that reads Excel.